# How to I parse json with dynamic response key

Tags: android, json, gson, retrofit2

How do I parse the following json response in retrofit

```
{
  "MH46AF4149": [
    {
      "distance": 74,
      "date": "23-09-2019"
    },
    {
      "distance": 97,
      "date": "24-09-2019"
    },
    {
      "distance": 91,
      "date": "25-09-2019"
    },
    {
      "distance": 80,
      "date": "26-09-2019"
    },
    {
      "distance": 91,
      "date": "27-09-2019"
    },
    {
      "distance": 16,
      "date": "28-09-2019"
    }
  ]
}
```

**MH46AF4149** is a `dynamic value` which keeps changing for every new response.

I am using RetrofitClient with GsonConverterFactory. How do I populate my model Class. Which annotation should I use. @Expose doesnt work

Comment: are you sure you will get different keys every time ? or you will get different date and distance each time?

Comment: different keys(Vehicleno) every time. The parameter distance and date are constants

Comment: check my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use **Key Iterator** for getting this dynamic Keys, like this way:

First **Store** your Json Response into one **JSONObject**.

```
JSONObject mainJSONObj=new JSONObject(responseString);

// get all keys from mainJSONObj
Iterator<String> iterator = mainJSONObj.keys();
  while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    String key = iterator.next();
    Log.e("Your Dynamic Key: ","-> "+key);
  }
```

Your **Retrofit2** Call should be like this:

```
Call<String> call = mApiInterface.myApi(yourBodyParams);

call.enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {

                JSONObject mainJSONObj=new JSONObject(response);

                // get all keys from mainJSONObj
                Iterator<String> iterator = mainJSONObj.keys();
                while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                    String key = iterator.next();
                    Log.e("Your Dynamic Key: ","-> "+key);

                    JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) mainJSONObj.getJSONArray(key);

                    if(jsonArray!=null){

                        for (int i = 0 ; i < jsonArray.length();i++){
                            JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                            String distance=jsonObject1.getString("distance");
                            String date=jsonObject1.getString("date");

                            Log.e("distance: ","-> "+distance);
                            Log.e("date: ","-> "+date);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {
                t.printStackTrace();
            });
```

This helps me; hope this will also helps you.

Comment: but how do i define my pojo class. i am very new to this. what value do i give for @SerializedName

Answer (score 1):

Follow below code,

```
JSONObject response = new JSONObject(responseString);
Iterator<?> keys = response.keys();
while( keys.hasNext() ) {
    String key = (String)keys.next();
    if ( response.get(key) instanceof JSONObject ) {
        JSONArray array = response.getJSONArray(key);
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++){
            JSONObject element = array.getJSONObject(i);
            //now use this array object to get strings
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get key like this

```
//if you have single key at that time use below code

 try {
           JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result.tostring);
            Iterator<String> keys = jsonObject.keys();
            String str_Name=keys.next();
            JSONArray jsonElements = (JSONArray) jsonObject.getJSONArray(str_Name);

//if you have multiple key you can get by for loop or while loop 

            while( keys.hasNext() ) {
                String key = (String)keys.next();
                JSONArray jsonElement = (JSONArray) jsonObject.getJSONArray(str_Name);
                for (int i = 0 ; i < jsonElement.length();i++){
                   JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonElement.getJSONObject(i);
                }

                }
            } catch (JSONException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

hope this may helps you.

```
public class Car {

        private String distance;
        private String date;

    }



Gson gson = new Gson();

    Type listType = new TypeToken<List<Car>>() {}.getType();
    List<Car> carList = null;
    try {
        jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);

        Iterator<String> keys = jsonResponse.keys();
        while (keys.hasNext()) {
            String key = (String) keys.next();
            if (jsonResponse.get(key) instanceof JSONArray) {
                JSONArray array = jsonResponse.getJSONArray(key);
               carList= gson.fromJson(array.toString(), listType);

                if (carList != null && carList.size() > 0) {

                }

            }
        }


    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```